# Evaluar un recordset con valor null

Tags: vb.net

Quiero verificar que el valor del recrodset es nulo para ingresar a un if, pero no se como es la sentencia de vb.net para evaluarlo.

Comment: Para confirmar, seguro que eso es lo que buscas? Que un recordset sea nulo significa que no tiene nada asignado ... pero quizás buscas saber si un recordset que sí tiene algo asignado ha devuelto algún valor. (o sea, si está vacío, en lugar de ser nulo)

Comment: se que uno de los resultados del recordset es que el valor sea nulo, o sea el atributo que busqué de la tupla, está sin valor asignado aún, y a partír de ese null trabajo un if en vb.net, pero no se como plantear la condicion del if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar Nothing

```
If (valor is Nothing) Then
    'Es null
End If
```

En dónde *valor* es lo que quieres comparar. No te entendí si es el recordset como tal o un valor en la colección:

```
rs is Nothing
```

ó

```
rs.Fields("NombreCampo").Value
```